# Laravel Facades in VueJS Template?

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I just created a symbolic link using this command `php artisan storage:link` to be able to access my files from the web. I've known this from Laravel's official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration.

And so I'm using `<img src="{{ Storage::url($user->avatar) }}">` in my blade template to get the path of my image.

My question is, how can I achieve similar approach using VueJS Template?
I tried `<img src="{{ Storage::url($user->avatar) }}">` in my `.vue` file but got an error when running `gulp watch`. The error throws an invalid expression. Simple means I can't use `Laravel's Facades` inside a `.vue` file?

What would be the best approach in getting the correct path of my image then? Use `$avatar = Storage::url($user->avatar);` and inject it to an array before getting it in `.vue` file?

For reference here's my:

**VueJS File**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="person in people">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    {{ person.name }}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img :src="person.avatar" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$http.get('/people/')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                this.people = res.body.people
            })
        },
        data() {
            return {
                people: '',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'people', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'PeopleController@index',
        'as' => 'people',
    ]);
});
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class PeopleController extends Controller
{
    public function index () {
        $people = User::all();
        return response()->json(['people' => $people]);
    }
}
```

Comment: uh.. i'm not familiar with vuejs, but.. laravel's `{{ ... }}` only works in **blade template**. so, although they had the same variable rendering command - `{{ ... }}` doesn't mean you can call laravel's function inside vue's. perhaps rendering storage url (`Storage::url($user->avatar)`) before passing data into vue using json is best.

Comment: @BagusTesa, Yeah, I think so. But that would be a pain trying to get the correct path for each data in an array. Maybe others have much better way or workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not set the storage path in your User model.
Create an `avatar_url` attribute in your model.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class User extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['avatar_url'];

    ....

    public function getAvatarUrlAttribute() {
        return Storage::url($this->avatar);
    }

    ...

}
```

Then in your VueJS file...

```
<img :src="person.avatar_url" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: Seems the easiest way. Can you please provide some docs in `protected $appends = [];`?

Comment: It is a property of Model that allows the attribute to be appended to the models serialization. It is referred to [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)